# Automated GUI testing of real-world desktop and/or web applications

Tags: automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, gui-testing

This is not so much a question, but rather a discussion about best practices with automated GUI testing in real-world applications  (where real-world aplications are applications that have more than two forms and three buttons and complexity that goes beyond calculating two numbers and displaying result in a texbox).

I searched the web about hands-on experience in automated GUI testing of real-world applications. Most of the articles presented very limited examples (i.e. testing simple calculator-style application) which are not useful for jump-starting automated GUI testing on an application with 100k+ LOC.

When implementing automated GUI testing I do not want to make beginner mistakes, so I'm asking you:

- What are your practices when you do automated GUI testing?
- What are the tools you use and why?
- How do you handle complex execution paths?
- ...

To be more concrete, let me describe the situation in more details:
We have 100k+ LOC project written in C#. It's a Windows application and interacts with hardware (various measurement units via different communication protocols). We have unit test for "general" features (libraries, etc.) - features that are independent and can be tested in isolation. Due to limitations of using real hardware we cannot test everything in an automated way (investment is too high) - but we could automate at least half the work our testers are doing now manually. I would like to "transform" some of our testers to manage automated UI tests. Our testers have limited programming skills, so the best workflow for our case would be either to record the UI tests or to use some simplified programming approach. Future maintenance of the UI tests should be done by testers (in contrast of unit tests where maintenance is done by the programmers).

- The application uses SQLite database for storing its configuration and data.
- The tests must be run against different sets of test data. How / where to store the data?
- When using more than one set of test data, "safe" state must be achieved before using next set of test data - a state where we are 100% sure, the application is OK. Do you prefer restarting the application or programmatically revert the changes you have made with a test? An example of this is logging in - login for every test or login once and do several test in a row?
- All tests should be run on at different Windows OS platforms (Win7/Win8, x86/x64) in mixed environment (virtual and physical).
- How do you run UI tests for components? Do you make simple test programs and do the UI testing using this program? Or maybe anything else?

Answer (score 3):

What are your practices when you do automated GUI testing?

- Record the page
- Auto generate methods so I can update the page
  easily

Avoid where ever you can. I'm currently looking at Unit testing with MVC. 
Build a way of easily updating your pages.
What are the tools you use and why?

1. [Specflow](http://www.specflow.org/) - for workflow testing
2. [T4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262201/codedui-map-generated-from-source-code/29271762#29271762) - for generating methods from pages
3. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) - for cross browser testing
4. [CUITe](https://cuite.codeplex.com/) - extending coded ui tests and recording

How do you handle complex execution paths?

1. With a architecture pattern such as [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
2. Model: Page mapping of ui controls
3. View(Navigation): How to navigate to the page and meet pre conditions and triggers
4. Controller : Test Method that calls the Navigation and Model

Follow up Questions :

- How often are you going to maintain these Coded UI Test?
- Who's going to maintain these tests?
- Please elaborate on "safe state", type, thread?
- How are you going to handle page loading?
- Are you going to do cross browser testing?
- Are you going to test in multiple environments?
- Are you going to test with multiple test agents?
- How are you going to generate test data?
- How are you going to store test data?
- Have you got unit tests?
- Are you doing manual tests?